# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" after user login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = guest.1@led.id limit 1**

After the user successfully signed in, I received this problem after uploading the Laravel project to hosting (Plesk).

This, my database.php

**'mysql' => [

  'driver' => 'mysql',

  'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),

  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),

  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),

  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'med'),

  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),

  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),

  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),

  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',

  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

  'prefix' => '',

  'prefix_indexes' => true,

  'strict' => true,

  'engine' => null,

  'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([

    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),

  ]) : [],

],**

And, this my .env

**DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=med

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=**

For local projects, it functions securely and user logins are unhindered.

What configurations must be altered for Plesk hosting to function properly?

Comment: This issue has been fixed. I just removed every file and folder on the hosting, then I uploaded everything again. I have no idea what occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed every file and folder on the hosting, then I uploaded everything again. I have no idea what occurred.